# c# webbrowser control , how to simulate ctrl+u

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows form application. I'm using `webbrowser` control in it. I would like to simulate the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> function to allows to showing the source code of html page.

Comment: when we simulate ctrl + u in a regular web browser (like chrome, Firfox, IE, ....), a new tab appears and contains the source code of the web page.
I want to create this fonction in my web browser control.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: You may use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`, see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [HOW TO: Invoke the Find, View Source, and Options Dialog Boxes for the WebBrowser Control from Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329014)

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this helps you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }

        // form which contains the web browser
        public partial class MainForm : Form
        {
            public WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
            public MainForm()
            {


                web.Height = this.Height;
                web.Width = this.Width;
                web.Top = 0;
                web.Left = 0;
                web.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                this.Controls.Add(web);

                web.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
            }
            protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
            {
                if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.U))
                {
                    SourceForm scr = new SourceForm(this.web);
                    scr.Show();

                    return true;
                }
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }


        //the form which will be shown once you press CTRL+U
        public class SourceForm : Form
        {
            public TextBox sourceText;
            public SourceForm(WebBrowser web)
            {
                sourceText = new TextBox();
                sourceText.Multiline = true;
                sourceText.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
                sourceText.Left = 0;
                sourceText.Top = 0;
                sourceText.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                sourceText.Height = this.Height;
                sourceText.Width = this.Width;
                this.Controls.Add(sourceText);
                this.sourceText.Text = web.DocumentText;
                this.Text = web.DocumentTitle;
            }
        }

    }
}
```